# kendo requirejs access viewmodel from another module

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, requirejs

how to 'get' and 'set' properties of one viewmode's from another requirejs module?

```
test.js
================
define(['kendo'],
   function (kendo) {
       var vm = kendo.observable({
           propertyA: "a"
       });
   return {vm: vm};
});

another.js
================
define(['kendo'],
   function (kendo) {
       var testMethod = function () {
           var test = require(['test']);
           var testName = test.vm.get("propertyA");      //<< uncaught typeerror ???
           test.vm.set("propertyA", "b");                //<< uncaught typeerror ???
       };
   return {testMethod: testMethod};
});
```

I'm sorry because I have a c# background and not used to work with js unless my current project.

Should I add methods to test.js vm to get and set the properties of the viewModel or are there another way I can get and set the properties (propertyA for this example) directly from another module?

Comment: What on earth is `var method = function({...});` supposed to do?

Comment: I have renamed method to testMethod. another.js is a library that can be used from other modules in the application without the need to get access to test.js viewModel.

Comment: The statement I referred to is not *syntactically* correct. Did you mean `var testMethod = function () {...};`?

Comment: yes sorry for that as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it the way you are doing it. Your call to `require` is *asynchronous*. So `test` won't have the value you want.

You could do it like this:

```
define(['kendo', 'test'], function (kendo, test) {
       var testMethod = function () {
           var testName = test.vm.get("propertyA");      //<< uncaught typeerror ???
           test.vm.set("propertyA", "b");                //<< uncaught typeerror ???
       };
   return {testMethod: testMethod};
});
```

Comment: Shall I get circular reference If I call testMethod from test.js itself? I think like this is ok If I call it from outside test.js Am I correct?

Comment: I am not sure whether you are correct so let me explain. You won't have a circular dependency if you modify your code as I suggested but the rest of your code remains as you've shown in the question. However, if in addition to what I suggest you *also* modify your `test.js` file so that it has `another` among its dependencies in order to use `testMethod`, then yes you will have a circular dependency. Other modules won't cause this issue.